German animation about hedgehogs crossing the street and flying cars?
I am looking for a German animation about hedgehogs crossing the street and the people finding solutions to the problem it caused, iirc one proposed solution was to make a tunnel below the street another involved flying cars. 
I watched this in the 90s, I am almost sure it was German because in one part there was a newspaper with the word "die" (the).

Reminiscent of when Crusty the Clown got the "Die Bart Die" tattoo...

I just realised how many Hedgehogs there are in German animated programs... do you remember if the hedgehogs where realistic or anthropomorphic? Also, if this helps, OP may have caught the German localisation of a Czech animation, we have a lot of those floating around.

They were realistic hedgehogs, iirc the animation was made to look like a documentary or educational.

I found it:
The film is "Als die Igel größer wurden" by Ursula Winzentsen and Franz Winzentsen.
